# Biological variance or truly affected genes.

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I am a biology student and in our lab we are testing some kind of medicine on mouse. Under normal state, we have many sets of gene expression data for biological replicates:

`gene                  replicate 1               replicate2
gene1                 -0.842138                 -0.701153
gene2                 -0.796896                 -0.725085
gene3                 -0.835920                 -0.707572
gene5                 -0.702721                 -0.724579
gene6                 -0.815476                 -0.737112
....
gene 20000`

[each dot represent a gene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z11FQ.png)

and after feeding them with medicine, we have a new gene expression data:
[after medicine treatment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv8bW.png)

My question is, how I can separate those truly affected genes from those that just biological variance(difference between replicates)?

I am new to machine learning, I believe supervised learning should be my option, right? The training data is my replicates data and then I can test whether each gene after medicine treatment can fall into the "tolerance zone" defined by replicates. But I am not sure which method should I use. Any guidance is appreciated in advance.

Comment: oh boy. I'd need a minute..

Answer (score 0):

First of all welcome to Stack Overflow! Secondly I really think that this question should be moved here: [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/). Nonetheless I will try to help you with an answer.

I've got a few questions, which when you answer you should be on the right way to actually solve this:

1. How did you split your data to training data(What percentage of the overall data are you using for training purposes)?
2. Have you established boundaries for the genes which were initially introduced to the chemical?
3. What variance were you expecting initially?
4. Have the boundaries of the variance significantly changed after the testing has been completed?
5. Which algorithms are you thinking of using for this specific problem?
6. Are you going to use [EDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis) in order to get better insight?
7. Have you thought of using **K-means** in order to observe how the clusters of data change after the introduction of the "new medicine"?

I'd personally would calculate mean and standard deviation for those genes and do the same after the medicine is introduced. This should help you gain some insight on how the boundaries are changed and where the spread is most likely occurring. Also, always use EDA if you have the option(I know I'm being quite preachy about this but it helps a lot). I think that this should help you to gain better insight on your problem. I hope that I've helped.

Useful link for algorithms: [Machine Learning Algorithms](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/common-machine-learning-algorithms/)

Comment: I'd suggest to do so. The best thing to do is to get familiar with the algorithms and do take a look at genetic algorithms as well. I hope my answer helped you out.

Comment: My question may be too naive... I should learn more statistical knowledge then ask...1. All the replicates data are my training data. 2. I think each gene expression data among replicates define the boundaries. like in my first scatter plot, the dotted area define the "tolerance zone", then after medicine treatment, I want to find which genes have significant changes(fall out tolerance zone) 7. It's indeed something like k-means cluster, expect that I don't know how to define cluster1(changes between replicates) and cluster2(significant affected genes after medicine treatment)

Comment: @AlicePsyche well you know what to read and where to start from. I'd suggest that you don't use your entire data as training data but split it to something like 30% to 70% or 40% to 60%. Check out **K-means** and familiarise yourself with how you should decide how many clusters you need. There are also quite a lot of code examples online regarding Machine Learning, especially in Python.

Comment: @ZombieChowder: the migrate opinion and your list of questions belong in comments, not an answer.

Comment: @Prune I guess you are right but I can't imagine someone actually answering this question. I'd be like writing a mini dissertation on it's own, so I thought about asking the right questions instead. I know I acted out of "protocol" but that's how I saw things.

Comment: I have no problem with what you asked; I merely suggest that the initial comment and the seven points move to comments.  I'd leave the final paragraph and the link in this answer.